# Unable to load URL

Tags: python, url, request

```
import requests
url = https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=ACC
data = requests.get('https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=ACC'')
print(data)
```

I'm trying to load data from above url but failed. How to do that? I got a `invalid syntax error`.

Comment: What printed when you ran it?

Comment: invalid syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two problems with your code.

### First problem

```
url = https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=ACC
```

- Not a proper variable assignment
- Missing quote for assigning string value

In this case `url` variable is a string so it should be:

```
url = "https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=ACC"
```

### Second problem

```
data = requests.get('https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=ACC'')
```

- Unnecessary extra `'` at the end of your url string

Remove the extra `'` and it should be:

```
data = requests.get('https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=ACC')
print(data)
```

Before asking a question on stackoverflow please re-consider to contemplate on your code and check for syntax error.

Comment: + For OCD writing style.

Comment: I tried but there is neither error nor any output. Can you run it and see where is the problem???

Comment: @BrijeshChaurasia What Ide/Text editor are you using? and are you sure python is properly installed in your computer?.

Comment: My other scripts are running well. I'm using pydroid3, the Android app. Due to my job I'm unable to use laptop.

Comment: @BrijeshChaurasia I tried to run your code but its not showing any output either, I think its because there's problem with requesting data from that link website itself (probably because its too big).

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
import requests
data = requests.get('https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=ACC')
print(data)
```

Saying `url = https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=ACC` is wrong because that is not a variable and has to be a string, plus you don't even need it. You also have an extra `'` behind your url.

Answer (score 0):

The decleration `url = https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=ACC`

the actual value should be quoted, because it is a string like `url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=ACC'`

Comment: Can you plz update your answer with full working script Plz so that I can get data

Comment: @BrijeshChaurasia Look at the answer by DialFrost for a copy-paste solution